# reddit JSON for comments

Tags: android, json

I'm pulling the following JSON in android

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/8r9uz9.json

I want the comments, which is the body field, but I can't seem to get it.  I'm sure I'm doing the inital JSON wrong but I can't see to work it out.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray children = new JSONArray(response).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("children");
               Log.v("test", "test:" + children.length());




                for (int i = 0; i<children.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = children.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");

                    Log.v("Fun", "Data:" + json_data.getString("body"));

                }
```

I'm pretty sure its do with getting the first jsonarray not selecting the first value in the array (the post code works fine).

Any suggestions on how I can pull the body data correctly for comments?

Thank you

Error message:

```
06-15 20:19:49.336 14089-14089/com.xV/Fun: Err:org.json.JSONException: Value [{"kind":"Listing","data":{"modhash":"","dist":1,"children":[{"kind":"t3","data":{"approved_at_utc":null,"subreddit":"AskReddit","selftext":"","user_reports":[],"saved":false,"mod_reason_title":null,"gilded":0,"clicked":false,"title":"Redditors who see a therapist, what made you go?","link_flair_richtext":[],"subreddit_name_prefixed":"r\/AskReddit","hidden":false,"pwls":6,"link_flair_css_class":null,"downs":0,"parent_whitelist_status":"all_ads","hide_score":true,"name":"t3_8r9uz9","quarantine":false,"link_flair_text_color":"dark","upvote_ratio":0.67,"author_flair_background_color":null,"subreddit_type":"public","ups":1,"domain":"self.AskReddit","media_embed":{},"author_flair_template_id":null,"is_original_content":false,"secure_media":null,"is_reddit_media_domain":false,"category":null,"secure_media_embed":{},"link_flair_text":null,"can_mod_post":false,"score":1,"approved_by":null,"thumbnail":"","edited":false,"author_flair_css_class":null,"author_flair_richtext":[],"content_categories":null,"is_self":true,"mod_note":null,"created":1529086635,"link_flair_type":"text","wls":6,"post_categories":null,"banned_by":null,"author_flair_type":"text","contest_mode":false,"selftext_html":null,"likes":null,"suggested_sort":null,"banned_at_utc":null,"view_count":null,"archived":false,"no_follow":true,"is_crosspostable":false,"pinned":false,"over_18":false,"media_only":false,"can_gild":false,"spoiler":false,"locked":false,"author_flair_text":null,"rte_mode":"markdown","visited":false,"num_reports":null,"distinguished":null,"subreddit_id":"t5_2qh1i","mod_reason_by":null,"removal_reason":null,"id":"8r9uz9","report_reasons":null,"author":"Lunaetyx","num_crossposts":0,"num_comments":7,"send_replies":true,"mod_reports":[],"author_flair_text_color":null,"permalink":"\/r\/AskReddit\/comments\/8r9uz9\/redditors_who_see_a_therapist_what_made_you_go\/","whitelist_status":"all_ads","stickied":false,"url":"https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/AskReddit\/comments\/8r9uz9\/redditors_who_see_a_therapist_what_made_you_go\/","subreddit_subscribers":19397994,"created_utc":1529057835,"media":null,"is_video":false}}],"after":null,"before":null}},{"kind":"Listing","data":{"modhash":"","dist":null,"children":[{"kind":"t1","data":{"subreddit_id":"t5_2qh1i","approved_at_utc":null,"ups":1,"mod_reason_by":null,"banned_by":null,"author_flair_type":"text","removal_reason":null,"link_id":"t3_8r9uz9","author_flair_template_id":null,"likes":null,"no_follow":true,"replies":"","user_reports":[],"saved":false,"id":"e0pjo47","banned_at_utc":null,"mod_reason_title":null,"gilded":0,"archived":false,"report_reasons":null,"author":"nonamesomeone","can_mod_post":false,"send_replies":true,"parent_id":"t3_8r9uz9","score":1,"approved_by":null,"downs":0,"body":"I used to see a therapist, basically when I started getting drunk and attempting suicide, I realised I might need some extra help. ","edited":false,"author_flair_css_class":null,"collapsed":false,"author_flair_richtext":[],"is_submitter":false,"collapsed_reason":null,"body_html":"&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;I used to see a therapist, basically when I started getting drunk and attempting suicide, I realised I might need some extra help. &lt;\/p&gt;\n&lt;\/div&gt;","stickied":false,"subreddit_type":"public","can_gild":true,"subreddit":"AskReddit","author_flair_text_color":null,"score_hidden":true,"permalink":"\/r\/AskReddit\/comments\/8r9uz9\/redditors_who_see_a_therapist_what_made_you_go\/e0pjo47\/","num_reports":null,"name":"t1_e0pjo47","created":1529086735,"author_flair_text":null,"rte_mode":"markdown","created_utc":1529057935,"subreddit_name_prefixed":"r\/AskReddit","controversiality":0,"depth":0,"author_flair_background_color":null,"mod_reports":[],"mod_note":null,"distinguished":null}},{"kind":"t1","data":{"subreddit_id":"t5_2qh1i","approved_at_utc":null,"ups":1,"mod_reason_by":null,"banned_by":null,"author_flair_type":"text","removal_reason":null,"link_id":"t3_8r9uz9","author_flair_template_id":null,"likes":null,"no_follow":true,"replies":"","user_repo
```

Comment: What do you see in logcat?

Comment: Apologies should of posted it:


06-15 20:19:49.336 14089-14089/com.xV/Fun: Err:org.json.JSONException: Value [{"kind":"Listing","data" (removed the rest as character limit)

Comment: It is too short to understand problem. Attach to question full log, please;

Comment: added error log to main post

Answer (score 0):

The **"children"** Object in your Your First **"data"** object doesn't have **"body"** element itself. check if your children.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data").has("body") then print log
I have Changed your method follow this and add catch block

```
    public void onResponse() {
    try {
        JSONArray parent = new JSONArray(yourJsonArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.length(); i++) {
            Log.v("parent ", "length:" + parent.length());

            JSONArray children = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                children = parent.getJSONObject(1).getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("children");
            }
            Log.v("children", "length:" + children.length());

            for (int j = 0; j < children.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject json_data = children.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("data");
                if (json_data.has("body")) {

                    Log.v("Fun ", "body:" + json_data.getString("body"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v("exception:", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortantely got the same error as before.   I'm pretty sure it has to be
 
children = new JSONArray(response).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("children");

Which is wrong somehow..

Comment: it throws an exception:: No value for body

Comment: check the edit I have added loop for the parent array also. if the object in child array has "body" value it will print.

Comment: Sabarinathan, Thank you so much for your help.   I realised it was probably due to how I was calling the JSON and I've changed that method, used your proposed code and it works perfectly now!